# Unable to access a Webapp on Tomcat in Vagrant box

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, web-applications, vagrant, forgerock

1. I have deployed a test application on Tomcat 9.0 installed on Vagrant (Ubuntu 14.04.6 trusty).
2. Placed the appropriate .war file in webapps path of the same Tomcat.
3. Configured the correct Connection port  (9980) in server.xml of Tomcat
4. Then also mentioned the desired FQDN in the /etc/hosts file as below.
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   127.0.0.1 am.label.com
5. Then I startup Tomcat.

I can see the tomcat server started successfully in the catalina.out log file.
I can also see the .war file extraction successful in the catalina.out log file.

But when I try to access the application on the Chrome through the configured FQDN I can't access anything. My tomcat running on Vagrant is still inaccessible.

The error on Chrome is --------

This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

PS. The .war file is packaged and provided by ForgeRock. I have verified the compatibility of the .war file with the corresponding tomcat and java versions.
It is the ForgeRock Access Manager .war file v7.3.x
Tomcat version 9.0
Java version is 11.0

Ubuntu version on vagrant is
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

Deployed the application in Tomcat running on Vagrant (ubuntu) box.
Expected result : Be able to view the app Console on Web browser (Chrome)